# gcc linker extension __attribute__((constructor)) causes crash in main()

Tags: c++, constructor, g++, function-attributes

First I've a singleton.cpp file to build a singleton object, and declare instance using **attribute**((constructor))

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
class singleton{
public:
    singleton(){cout<<"singleton ctor\n";}
};
__attribute__((constructor)) static void beforeFunction()
{
    printf("beforeFunction\n");
    singleton obj;
}
```

And a simple main.cpp

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    return 0;
}
```

I build main.cpp singleton.cpp together:

```
g++ singleton.cpp main.cpp -o main

./main
beforeFunction
Segmentation fault
```

So why my program crashes, what happened? How to fix it? I'm using gcc on ubuntu. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I reproduced this with `g++ (Debian 7.3.0-5)`, and also `g++ (GCC) 9.0.0 20180902 (experimental)`.

It's interesting that this fails:

```
$ g++ singleton.cpp main.cpp && ./a.out
beforeFunction
Segmentation fault
```

but this works as expected:

```
$ g++ main.cpp singleton.cpp && ./a.out
beforeFunction
singleton ctor
```

As Acorn correctly stated, the `iostream` / `std::cout` machinery has not been properly initialized by the time you called singleton constructor. This is happening because there is special code emitted into `main.o` (and *only* `main.o`) which calls `std::ios_base::Init::Init()`. And only because `main.cpp` has extraneous `#include <iostream>`.

> How to fix it?

The best fix is to not use `__attribute__((constructor))` *at all*. In your case, there is no reason to do what you are doing. Do this instead:

```
// singleton2.cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class singleton{
  public:
    singleton(){cout<<"singleton ctor\n";}
};

static singleton obj;
```

With above code, either order of linking works:

```
$ g++ main.cpp singleton2.cpp && ./a.out
singleton ctor

$ g++ singleton2.cpp main.cpp && ./a.out
singleton ctor
```

If you insist on using `__attribute__((constructor))`, then make sure `main.o` is on your link line *before* any other object that could use `iostream`s.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that `main.cpp singleton.cpp` order only works because there is a stray `#include <iostream>` in `main.cpp`.

Answer (score 1):

> So why my program crashes, what happened?

Most likely, the `iostream` machinary is not initialized yet at the time the `__attribute__((constructor))` functions are run.

> How to fix it?

Either use C I/O like `printf`, which seems to work in your case; or better, avoid using `__attribute__((constructor))` altogether (it is not standard C nor C++, i.e. it makes your program non-portable).

Note that there is no need for `__attribute__((constructor))` to create singletons or global objects.

Answer (score 1):

`std::cout` is initialized with the help of a static C++ object, see `<iostream>`:

```
  // For construction of filebuffers for cout, cin, cerr, clog et. al.
  static ios_base::Init __ioinit;
```

Since your code relies both on this static constructor and has an ELF constructor, it runs into this [GCC limitation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html#index-constructor-function-attribute):

> However, at present, the order in which constructors for C++ objects with static storage duration and functions decorated with attribute `constructor` are invoked is unspecified.

If you use a C++ object instead, the order is well-defined.  The GCC manual also suggests to use the [`init_priority` attribute](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C_002b_002b-Attributes.html#index-init_005fpriority-variable-attribute), but since you cannot apply it to the definition of `__ioinit` (except through preprocessor hackery), I do not think this is helpful in this context.