# Variable not set inside __attribute__((constructor)) or global static variable reset after __attribute__((constructor)) invoked

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, shared-libraries

I have a `std::vector` which need to filled with some random values when library is loaded. but I see it is been reset after library is loaded. Is it because of `global` and `static`

Library code:

```
static std::vector<uint8_t> g_randomNr{};


__attribute__((constructor)) void generateRandomNrAtStart(void)
{
    static bool firstLoad = false;
    g_randomNr.clear();
    if (!firstLoad) {
        firstLoad = true;
        std::cout << "Library is loaded and generating first random number ...\n";
    }

    std::cout << "Generating random number ...\n";


    for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
        g_randomNr.push_back(i);
    }

    std::cout << "Random number generated with length of " << g_randomNr.size() << "\n";
}

void getRandomNr(std::vector<uint8_t>& randomNr)
{
    randomNr = g_randomNr;
}
```

Main code:

```
int main()
{
    std::vector<uint8_t> randomNr{};
    getRandomNr(randomNr);
    
    std::cout << randomNr.size() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
Library is loaded and generating first random number ...
Generating random number ...
Random number generated with length of 20
0
```

In the above output I expect 20 in cout `main` function but I receive empty `vector`

Comment: `static std::vector<uint8_t> g_randomNr = makeRandomVector();` would avoid (non standard) attribute, issue of order between the global and that function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another option is to control the order of the vector initialization and constructor call with *priorities*:

```
__attribute__((init_priority(101))) static std::vector<uint8_t> g_randomNr{};

__attribute__((constructor(102))) void generateRandomNrAtStart() { ... }
```

Live demo: https://godbolt.org/z/bh9zj9cE3

Possibly OT to the problem: Note that using I/O (as `std::cout` in your case) in a constructor can suffer from the very same problem. See, e.g., [gcc linker extension __attribute__((constructor)) causes crash in main()](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54724470/580083).

Comment: Thank you very much for this answer it worked I struggled for a day behind this

Answer (score 2):

You are most likely suffering from a [*static initialization order fiasco*](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/siof).

I suggest lazy initialization of the `vector`:

```
auto& instance() {
    static std::vector<uint8_t> g_randomNr;
    return g_randomNr;
}
```

Then in your shared library constructor:

```
__attribute__((constructor)) void generateRandomNrAtStart(void)
{
    auto& g_randomNr = instance();
    // ...
```

And also in the function making a copy:

```
void getRandomNr(std::vector<uint8_t>& randomNr)
{
    randomNr = instance();
}
```